# Migrate a SharePoint list with "Related Items" column field

Tags: sharepoint-online, column

I need to migrate a SharePoint list with "`Related Items`" column field content of all list items to a completely new SharePoint environment.

It does not work when saved the template of the list and imported into the new tenant.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it via CSOM API.

Here is a simple demo for your reference:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// retreive data of data table from list
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="siteUrl"></param>
    /// <param name="listName"></param>
    /// <param name="columnNameArr"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DataTable retreiveDataFromListToDataTable(string siteUrl, string listName, string[] columnNameArr)
    {
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
        List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
        FieldCollection fields = list.Fields;
        CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
        ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

        //load data
        clientContext.Load(list);
        clientContext.Load(fields);
        clientContext.Load(items);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        //create a dataTable which will insert into the database
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("table");

        //init the structure of dataTable
        foreach (string columnName in columnNameArr)
        {
            DataColumn dataColumn = new DataColumn(columnName);
            dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
        }

        //fill the dataTable
        foreach (ListItem item in items)
        {
            DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
            foreach (string columnName in columnNameArr)
            {

                Object obj = item[columnName];
                dataRow[columnName] = (item[columnName] == null ? "" : item[columnName].ToString());

            }
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }

        return dataTable;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// recovery data of list from data table
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="siteUrl"></param>
    /// <param name="listName"></param>
    /// <param name="columnNameArr"></param>
    /// <param name="dataTable"></param>
    public static void recoveryDataFromDataTableToList(string siteUrl, string listName, string[] columnNameArr, DataTable dataTable)
    {
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
        List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
        FieldCollection fields = list.Fields;
        CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
        ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

        //load data
        clientContext.Load(list);
        clientContext.Load(fields);
        clientContext.Load(items);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


        foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
            ListItem oListItem = list.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
            foreach (string columnName in columnNameArr)
            {
                string data = row[columnName].ToString();                                       
                oListItem[columnName] = data;                  
                oListItem.Update();

                clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
            }
        }         

    }
```